# ASP.net display LoginStatus in masterpage by checking Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, session-state

I just want to put `LogIn Status` text in MY ASP master page. When User not logged IN it will show `LogIn` and If user already `logged In` it will show `LogOut`. Once user Clicked `logOut` ,session will be clear .

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" onviewchanged="LoginView1_ViewChanged">
       <AnonymousTemplate>
              <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LoginText="logIn" />
       </AnonymousTemplate>
       <LoggedInTemplate>
              <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus2" runat="server" LogoutText="loggedout"  />
       </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I am using `using System.Web.SessionState;` to manage session. I can check user is login or not by using bellow code.

```
If (Session["logged"] == true)
```

Please help me to display `LogIn` or `logOut` Status in Master page in Dynamically according to current session status. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoginView` control uses the current request's identity to determine whether or not they are logged in, and also the principal's role memberships, if you use the feature where you can show different templates for different roles. So, you won't be able to achieve what you wish using `LoginView`. Same thing with `LoginStatus`.

You can roll your own versions of those controls to do what you wish, or attempt to derive your own control from those controls and simply override the part where it figures out if you're logged in or not.

Alternately, you can just place something like this in your master page.

```
<% if (Session["logged"] is bool && (bool)Session["logged"]) {%>
 Logged in
%> } else { %>
 Logged out
<% } %>
```

However, I'd recommend you just rely on the request's identity to determine whether or not a user is logged in. A) it's built-in, fully supported, and you don't have to do anything extra B) Sessions are not durable. You can access the request's user in a page, control, etc. by accessing the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property.